# Dimple.js Stacked Bar Graph

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I have data for the different phases of a series of map reduce jobs in the following format:

```
{"GC Time":"[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]",
 "Result Serialization Time":"[3.0,3.0,3.0,2.0]",
 "Getting Result Time":"[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]",
 "Task Deserialization Time":"[17.0,16.0,16.0,16.0]",
 "Scheduler Delay":"[55.0,46.0,47.0,46.0]"}
```

Essentially, the array for each phase contains the times taken for that phase in increasing task number order.

I want to plot a stacked bar graph like the following using dimple.js/d3.js:

http://ibin.co/1yH9raFgUtPs

I'm not being able to figure out how to do this (should be pretty simple for someone who's good with dimple.js), so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be much easier to help you if you could show what you have done so far.

Nevertheless, I think the way you have defined your data is wrong.

Try defining your array something like this:

```
var xpoints=["a","b","c"];
var ypoints=[1,2,3];
var x2points=[5,6,7];
var dataset=[];
for(var i=0;i<xpoints.length;i++){
dataset.push({
                    x : xpoints[i],
                    y : parseFloat(ypoints[i]),                         
                    z : x2points[i]

                    });
        }

console.log(dataset);

/*Output:

[[object Object] {
  x: "a",
  y: 1,
  z: 5
}, [object Object] {
  x: "b",
  y: 2,
  z: 6
}, [object Object] {
  x: "c",
  y: 3,
  z: 7
}]

*/
```

Hope it helps!